# Svelte store not updating subscribed value synchronously

Tags: store, svelte

I have a component with header which displays title. I want to update title when I change pages, so I've created a store:

```
export const sectionTitle = writable<string>('');
```

I set store value in component:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import {sectionTitle} from "../lib/_store";

  sectionTitle.set('About');
</script>
```

And then subscribe to it in header:

```
<script lang="ts">
  let title;

  sectionTitle.subscribe(value => {
    title = value;
  })
</script>
...
<h1>{title}</h1>
```

It does work, but seems it works asynchronously - when I switch pages, it updates after I leave page or refresh it. Like it updates after the mount and doesn't update the title property. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? The behaviour I want is to update title prop when I load a page.

Comment: You should generally not subscribe to stores manually, if you do, you should also cancel the subscription. You can just [use the store directly](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values): `<h1>{$sectionTitle}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

By updating the title from within the component you couple the title update to how long it takes to load the component. Depending on the router you are using, the component may be loaded asynchronously which then causes a delayed update of the title, so the problem is not Svelte itself ([see this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/52cbddf91e514ef990faaf1c000947b5?version=3.49.0) where components are not loaded asynchronously).

I would recommend associating components/routes with titles elsewhere, e.g. in your header or a separate file, that way the title is known immediately and can be shown as soon as the route is changed.

Comment: I suspected that much. I found a way. I've created a ts file with all pages (I'm not going to add any backend, so pages will be static array) and their path/title. Then I've added this function to header:

let pagePath = $page.url.pathname;

  function getPageTitle() {
    return pages.find((page) => page.href === pagePath).label;
  }

and used it in place of title prop. It works like a charm.